# ast.literal_eval ValueError('malformed string')

Tags: python

I have a string of the form `{"Top":[{"A":1,"B":721.0,"C":false}]}` which I would like to convert into a Python collection.

I tried using `ast.literal_eval` like this:

```
x = '{"Top":[{"A":1,"B":721.0,"C":false}]}'
print ast.literal_eval(x)
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
File "queryFlights.py", line 19, in <module>
    print ast.literal_eval(x)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 63, in _convert
    in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 60, in _convert

    return list(map(_convert, node.elts))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 63, in _convert
    in zip(node.keys, node.values))
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert

    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

How can I convert that string into a collection?

Answer (score 6):

`false` is not accepted by `ast.literal_eval`.

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('false')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

`False` is

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('False')
False
```

but you probably want to use  `json.loads` instead since your string looks like valid json (and `json.loads` is faster than `ast.literal_eval` for evaluating json strings)...

```
>>> import json
>>> x = '{"Top":[{"A":1,"B":721.0,"C":false}]}'
>>> json.loads(x)
{u'Top': [{u'A': 1, u'C': False, u'B': 721.0}]}
```